# reformatting x axis as date in a heat map in ggplot

Tags: date, heatmap

I am trying to make a heat map using ggplot and I am having trouble formatting the x axis as a date.
When I run the basic code

`ggplot(kbsdiv13CTN, aes(x=date, y=rev(depth), fill=mean)) +
    geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") +
    scale_y_reverse()`

The heat map looks ok, but the dates are in the wrong order, and the x axis labels are really crowded together.

But then I reformat the x axis as date 
    `kbsdiv$date<- as.Date(kbsdiv$date , format = "%m/%d")`

`ggplot(kbsdiv13CTN, aes(x=date, y=rev(depth), fill=mean)) +
   geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") +
   scale_y_reverse() +
   scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("weeks"),labels = date_format("%b"))`
. 
and the heat map tiles become really narrow and no longer fill up the image. They basically look like very narrow bars, and it no longer looks like a heat map. I wanted to post a picture but they would not let me.

Can someone help?